# Toshiba A205-5804 freezes when plugged in

Tags: freeze, toshiba-laptop

Well I have a Toshiba A205-5804 and the problem is that the screen freezes anytime I plug the pc into the external power supply, not as most of the computers having the same issue, my computer DOES freeze in safe mode, and I really can't bear this problem for much longer...
It's not an overheating problem, the computer is not getting hot or anything related, I've already tried changing the AC adapter, booting only with AC and no battery, and also all of these suggestions:

> Try changing the following setting in the bios setup, under the
>   'Advanced' tab Dynamic CPU Frequency: 
>   Mode = Always Low (NOT DYNAMIC)  My
>   laptop has been running on AC power
>   without a problem for 24hours,
>   including many restarts, and when I
>   went back to the original bios
>   setting, the problem returned almost
>   straight away.
>
> EDIT
>
> Other suggestions I found on the web
>   from here and here:
>
> 1. Set the power plan to high performance
> 2. Set the power plan to "Minimal Power
>      Management" (1 and 2 do conflict)
> 3. Start -> Control Panel -> Device
>      Manager --> Processor -> disable one
>      of two processors -> reboot normally
>      4.Do this: Only plug battery into laptop
>      Turn on the laptop and start Windows
>      normally Plug AC adapter into laptop,
>      the screen will freeze Leave the
>      laptop the way it is for 12-24 hours
>      After 12-24 hours, turn it off the
>      hard way Once it is turned off, turn
>      it back on. The laptop is working now.

I have no idea of what can it be...

Answer (score 2):

I tried this and surprisingly it worked - the only thing I did not do is wait 12-24 hours (who could???); I followed 1-2 and did 3 differently. I opened Start > Run (instead of going to Device Manager because when I tried that it did not work for me) and typed "msconfig". There are five tabs: General, **Boot**, Services, Startup and Tools...

1. **Select Boot**
   Advanced Options is in that menu.
2. **Select Advanced Options**
   Here you are going to see the **number of processors**; click the drop-down and select **"1"**, press OK and then **restart normally (so that the settings are saved)** with or without the AC adapter.

> 1. Set the power plan to *High Performance*.
> 2. Set the power plan to *Minimal Power Management* (1 and 2 do conflict).
> 3. Start > Control Panel > Device Manager > Processor > disable one of the two processors > reboot normally.
> 4. Only plug the battery into the laptop. Turn on the laptop and start Windows normally.
> 5. Plug the AC adapter into the laptop; the screen will freeze.
> 6. Leave the laptop the way it is for 12-24 hours.
> 7. After 12-24 hours, turn it off the hard way. Once it is turned off, turn it back on.
>
> The laptop should be working now.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem; after it was sent to repair, it was found that the issue is with the power regulator on the motherboard components.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known problem with many models of Toshiba Satellite laptops and it is related to a bad capacitor called NEC/TOKIN Proadlizer, which loses its capacitance with time. One can either use temporary solutions of working in safe mode, disbaling cores, etc or a permanent solution of capacitor replacement. What type of cap to use and how to replace it has been shown here: http://gs138.photobucket.com/groups/q251/S1BXDWUERU/

Comment: Link is dead. Any chance of the images being hosted in a more permanent location?