# Acer Aspire One (mini) mfgd 9/03 locks up also when plugged in

Tags: freeze, hardware-failure

My problem is almost the same as the Toshiba user ([Toshiba A205-5804 freezes when plugged in](https://superuser.com/q/165138/151431)):

> Well I have a Toshiba A205-5804 and the problem is that the screen
>   freezes anytime I plug the pc into the external power supply, not as
>   most of the computers having the same issue, my computer DOES freeze
>   in safe mode, and I really can't bear this problem for much longer...
>   It's not an overheat problem, the computer is not getting hot or
>   anything related, I've tried already to change the AC adapter, to boot
>   only with AC and no battery, and also all of these suggestions:

The only difference in my case is, I can be using the battery and when it runs down, I can just close the lid and the system goes into hibernation mode. I then plug it in and let it charge. When I think it's finally charged, I can UNPLUG it, open the lid and all is running fine on the battery again. Note: the system was NOT shut down and it still runs as long as I remove the power plug before opening the lid.
I have ALL the same issues as the other Toshiba user, also.

I was a tech for 9 yrs in my own business and this one has not only stumped me, but anyone I have asked has never heard of this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Based on many years of repairing notebooks, it sounds like something is most likely broken.

The easiest/most likely culprit is your AC adapter, so start with that.  Beyond that it is likely faulty voltage controllers on the motherboard itself.

Unless you have the time and parts to start diagnosing and replacing, then you're going to have to have someone who does do it, and since it's out of warranty you'll probably have to (gasp) pay them. :)